# How to show/hide fields shown in Filter, Group By selection?

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-10, odoo-view

Hello I am trying to hide/show some fields in Action (Tree view) Filter/Group By fields selection section. I found solution to do that with fields_get function, but then I have problem that when you switch between menu items, fields does not renew. My solution is Below.

```
@api.model
def fields_get(self, allfields=None, attributes=None):
    """Extend to hide fields from custom search."""
    # u'route_view': u'route_accounting'
    # Fieldai kuriuos reikia rodyti
    route_accounting_filter = ['last_adt', 'first_alt', 'carrier', 'cmr_receive_date',
                               'cmr_reg_no_1', 'cmr_req',
                               'cmr_send_date', 'send_seperate_documents',
                               'freight_customer', 'last_invoice_send_date',
                               'load_country_id', 'load_full_adr', 'last_relevant_invoice',
                               'payer', 'customer', 'other_po',
                               'purchase_order_route_loc', 'name', 'freight_so',
                               'trailer_id', 'truck_id', 'unload_country_id',
                               'unload_full_adr', 'billing_data', 'invoice_billing_no',
                               'cmr', 'cmr_copy_receive_date', 'debt',
                               'declaration', 'last_invoice_send_date', 'transportation_done',
                               'delivery_note', 'document_packet', 'documents_delayed_to_receive',

                               'transportation_done_date', 'last_invoice_send_date', 'cmr_reg_userr',
                               'cmr_reg_date', 'product_description'

                               ]

    route_accounting_group = ['name', 'last_adt', 'first_alt', 'carrier', 'cmr_reg_date'
                              'cmr_reg_userr', 'cmr_req', 'freight_customer', 'payer', 'load_country_id',
                              'trailer_id', 'truck_id', 'unload_country_id', 'product_route_id'
                              ]

    other_route_group = ['other_po_carrier', 'other_so_partner', 'other_po_description',
                         'other_po_truck', 'other_po_trailer', 'ferry_product', 'other_so_partner',
                         'other_po_carrier', 'other_po_description', 'other_po_truck', 'other_po_trailer',
                         'other_po_carrier_loading_time', 'other_po_carrier_unloading_time',
                         'last_relevant_bill_number'
    ]

    other_route_filter = ['name', 'other_so', 'other_po',
                         'vendor_reference_other', 'transportation_done', 'ferry_product', 'name'
                         ]

    res = super(RouteData, self).fields_get(
        allfields=allfields,
        attributes=attributes
    )

    if 'route_view' in self.env.context and self.env.context['route_view'] == 'route_accounting':
        print "ROUTE (ACCOUNTING VIEW))))"
        for field in res:
            if field not in route_accounting_filter:
                res[field]['selectable'] = False

        for field in res:
            if field not in route_accounting_group:
                res[field]['sortable'] = False

    elif 'route_view' in self.env.context and self.env.context['route_view'] == 'route_other':
        print "ROUTE (OTHER VIEW))))"
        for field in res:
            if field not in other_route_filter:
                res[field]['selectable'] = False

        for field in res:
            if field not in other_route_group:
                res[field]['sortable'] = False

    return res
```

My view looks like shown in picture. Basically each menu item has its own action, but is from same table and I believe for this Reason even tho my solution checking contexts works (it prints out that he is in different view) he doesn't renew fields that are shown in Group By/Filter (even tho code works). Is there something that I forgot or maybe there is different solution to accomplish this easily? (Would be very nice if I didn't need to use JS)

[image]

Comment: a good question

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I understand the question. Anyway take a look at my suggestions:

### Solution 0

If I understood well you just want to modify the search view. For example if some search view look like this:

```xml
<record id="original_search_view" model="ir.ui.view">
    <field name="name">name.search</field>
    <field name="model">model.name</field>
    <field name="arch" type="xml">
        <search string="Partner Record">
            <field name="partner_id" string="Partner" filter_domain="[('partner_id','ilike',self)]"/>
            <field name="operation_key" string="Operation key" filter_domain="[('operation_key','ilike',self)]"/>
            <field name="partner_vat" string="Record" filter_domain="['|',('partner_vat','ilike',self),('partner_id','ilike',self)]"/>
            <separator/>

            <filter name="draft_filter" domain="[('state', '=', 'draft')]"/>

            <group expand="0" string="Group by..." >
                <filter string="Operation key" domain="[]" context="{'group_by' : 'operation_key'}"/>
            </group>
        </search>
    </field>
</record>
```

You can change it by inheritance like this

```xml
<record id="custom_search_view" model="ir.ui.view">
    <field name="name">custom.name.search</field>
    <field name="model">model.name</field>
    <field name="inherit_id" ref="module_name.original_search_view" />
    <field name="arch" type="xml">
        <!-- remves parnet_vat field from filters -->
        <field name="partner_vat" position="replace" />
        <filter name="draft_filter" position="replace" />

        <!-- removes group by filters -->
        <xpath expr="/search/group[1]" position="replace" />
    </field>
</record>
```

**Note**: Be careful removing items. Sometimes other modules can add more fields to the original view and they may need the original fields to get the position. So you may make them invisible instead of removing them completely.

### Solution 1

You can create a new search view from scratch and add it to the action window with the `search_view_id` field like this:

```xml
<record model="ir.actions.act_window" id="credit_control_line_action">
    <field name="name">Credit Control Lines</field>
    <field name="type">ir.actions.act_window</field>
    <field name="res_model">model.name</field>
    <field name="domain"></field>
    <field name="view_type">form</field>
    <field name="view_mode">tree,form</field>
    <field name="view_id" ref="custom_tree_view"/>

    <!-- filters selected by default, the format is: { 'search_default_[filter_name]': 1, }  -->
    <field name="context">{'search_default_filter_draft': 1, 'search_default_filter_to_be_sent': 1}</field>

    <!-- this search view is going to be used instead of the default view -->
    <field name="search_view_id" ref="custom_search_view"/>
</record>
```

**Note**: More information about search views on the [Odoo Documentation](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/10.0/reference/views.html#search)

Comment: Thanks for very informative answer. That's a good answer, and it is something that I am using right now. The problem with search is that you can't do conditions (like is greater/less then date etc.). You can do those conditions with filter button. The problem is my table has tons of fields, but I only want to see let's say 15 fields. The solution that I gave with fields get is good. But problem is that when you switch between menuitems (Other Route, Route(Accounting) in image) The filter are not being renewed. Anyways thank you for your answer :).

Comment: Yes, you can write conditions filling the `filter_domain` attribute. I think I am not understanding well your question. Do you mean that you want a different number of columns to each view? Do you need a special and complex `filter_domain`?

Comment: Do you mean that you want a special filtering while typing your word to search into the searchbox?

Comment: No. Forget the search box. Under search box there is a Filter (look at screenshot) and group by buttons. I need to remove fields that are displayed in Filter. And my solution with fields_get does that, except when you switch between menuitems.

Comment: OK, then my answer is right. You can use fields, filters and group by filters on the search views. You want to remove the filters. I have added a filter to my example: `<filter name="draft_filter" domain="[('state', '=', 'draft')]"/>`. You can create a new search view without the filters and add it to the action as my second solution or you can modify the original search view by inheritance and remove the filter elements: `<filter name="draft_filter" position="replace" />`